# "This undertaking led in 1875 to a commission from the railway"

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence, I can't correctly understand the meaning of "This undertaking led in 1875 to a commission from the railway". By the way, what is the word "commission" here mean? Could you help me clarify this?

> This undertaking led in 1875 to a commission from the railway to record the principal structures along the almost-completed line connecting Montreal to Halifax.

Comment: [**commission**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/commission) - An instruction, command, or role given to a person or group. Ex: *One of his first commissions was to redesign the Great Exhibition building*.

Answer (score 1):

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noun):

> **commission** noun
>
> com·​mis·​sion | \ kə-ˈmi-shən \
> *plural* commissions
>
> 1 a : a formal written warrant granting the power to perform various acts or duties

Your quote lacks context, but I assume “the undertaking” refers to a prior project that was completed successfully, which led to getting a commission for a new project in 1875.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think it's the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: The result of 'this undertaking' was that, in 1875, the railway commissioned a team (gave them the authority) to report on the principal structures...